# What is the best word to describe these utensils?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

[image: wooden utensils]

In English I suppose I would call it a "scoop", although that's ambiguous. I think I've heard it called a "cuillere à grosselle" (not sure of the spelling), but googling for that turns up nothing. Is there a dedicated word for one of these objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selon ce qu'on ramasse avec, ça s'appelle *pelle à farine*, *pelle à sucre*, *pelle à bonbon*, *pelle à gros sel*, *pelle à grain*...

Donc, pas *cuillère* contrairement à l'anglais *spoon*. Et pas *pelle* tout court, qui fait penser à l'outil pour creuser des trous dans la terre.

Comment: Dans certains cas, ça peut être une cuillère, par exemple *ice cream scoop* = *cuillère à glace*.

Comment: Pelle à gros sel rend en effet plus de résultats Google que cuillère. Ou pelle à thé dans mon cas.

Comment: @Gilles - Les cuillères à glace n'ont pas cette forme.

Comment: @mouviciel Oui, pardon, je voulais dire que le mot *scoop* est traduit par *cuillère* dans certains contextes mais je n'ai pas été clair.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found it minutes after posting the question. Turns out the corect spelling was "cuillère à *gros sel*" ("rock salt spoon"). The scant results in google for that query indicate that that's probably not a super common name, though.

Not sure if I should leave this question up or not - other readers might find it interesting.

Comment: I do. Please keep it!